# Are there any promiscuous woman present in muslim epic stories?

Tags: prophet-isa, hindu

In Hindu epic Ramayana, Shurpanakha seduces Laxman.

Ahalya commits adultery and later cursed by Gautama Maharishi..

---

In Christianity epic stories, Mary Magdalene tried to seduce Jesus but Jesus told her what His mission.

What about Muslim side including myth characters?

Comment: As a side note, many denominations within Christianity & Islam do not believe the myth of Mary Magdalene.

Comment: Zuleikha in the story of Joseph.

Comment: @UmH Don't you want to convert that into answer?

Comment: @Ahmed I want Myth characters also.

Comment: Myths or fictional stories are not on topic for this site since that would be cultural rather than Islamic.